# In iOS keychain app what does common name means?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first time creating a certificate. While creating the .CSR file I found the field common name but have no idea what this means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating certificate signing request in Keychain Access: which private key is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947314/generating-certificate-signing-request-in-keychain-access-which-private-key-is)

Comment: I found [this](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO7239.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here I got the common name in detail](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO7239.html)